# Use two SetOnClickListener in the MainActivity

Tags: android, listeners

I am developing an Android app. The topic is a cost manager.
I want to use two `SetOnClickListener` in the mainactivity for two buttons.
The first button change the view to a second page (activity). And on this page there is a second button, which just print out an log message.
But the app break down and do not throw an error message. The failure has to be in the second `onClickListener`, because without it, it works.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init all Elements
        Button btn_hinzufügen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        Button btn_speichern = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speichern);



        btn_hinzufügen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                open_add_data();

            }
        });

        btn_speichern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Info", "Say Hello");
            }
        });
    }


    public void open_add_data() {
        setContentView(R.layout.add_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.add_data);` will not move to next page. This sets the current page view

Comment: Better to use **[`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** if you want to display multiple layout in same activity

Comment: It can't work like that. If your second button is on a second screen managed by a second Activity, the `onClickListener` for the second button should be created in the second Activity. Here you app crashes because your MainActivity can't find the second button in its layout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setContentView(R.layout.add_data);` on button click you should try to manage visibility of both layout.

Comment: the op wants to move to next page .  `The first button change the view to a secound page (activity).`  --> need to use intent or deal with fragments which is better one

Comment: And how i should do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both of your buttons are contained in activity_main.xml layout then only you can instantiate two buttons in same activity. If not move second button to your second activity.